# Q: Find the sum of the first 300 terms of the series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Q: Find the sum of the first 300 terms of the series $$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$$

I have no idea thankyou

Comment: Hint:  $1+2+3+\dots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ so $\frac{1}{k}+\frac{2}{k}+\frac{3}{k}+\dots+\frac{k}{k}=\frac{k+1}{2}$.

Comment: The tedious part is seeing which one is the 300th term. The rest is pretty much just Gauss' formula for the sum of the first $n$ integers.

Comment: Another heavy hint: speaking of denominators, there's one $1$, two $2s$, three $3s$, etc. Also, $\frac 12 (24)(24+1) = 300$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every time a new denominator $k$ appears, it appears $k$ times, the $300$th term is $n(n+1)=600$ which has positive solution $24$, this means that you want to compute the sum 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{24}\left(\frac 1i \sum_{k=1}^i k\right)$$
As JMoravitz noted, the inner sum evaluates to $\frac {i+1}{2}$, therefore we have 
$$\frac 12\sum_{i=1}^{24}i+1=\frac 12 \left(\frac {24(24+1)}{2}+24\right)$$